# how to remove dynamically inflated views?

Tags: android

In a simple card game that i want to develop, I have three buttons: button1,button2 and button3. button1 creates two imageviews in a tablerow and displays the image. When button2 and/or button3 is clicked, it dynamically adds imageview on the tablerow through layout inflater. When game is over, I want user to click button1 and start things all over again. I am able to do that but the problem is, the imageviews that were previously displayed by clicking button2 and button3 also displays. I want them to be removed when button1 is clicked. How can I remove them on click of button1? 
Please help me!

Answer (score 7):

Just like you added views, you can remove them. Just call `removeViewAt(int index)` or `removeView(View view)` on the parent container to remove the view(s) you want.

Alternatively, if you foresee reusing them, you can just set their visibility to `GONE`. Then you could bring them back without the expense of inflating them again.

If you're letting the inflater automatically attach the inflated imageviews to the parent, then you'll have to keep track of the position of the added views. You can use `getChildCount` on the parent just before inflating to find the index of the next view that will be added.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ViewGroup.removeView(View v);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29)

something like this:

```
tblRow.removeView(button2);
```

Comment: I did that but it doesnot add imageview when I click button1. I just want to remove the imageviews that are displayed by layout inflater. And i dont want to remove button!! I want to remove imageViews.

Comment: then pass removeView() a reference to the ImageView you want to remove instead of a button. If you edit your question and post some code that you are using it would be far easier for us to give you a specific solution. As it is now it is somewhat difficult to tell exactly what is going on in your program based on what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I add then remove a View 5 seconds later (in another context)

```
  final LinearLayout linearLayout = context.getResources().getLayout(R.layout.activity_main)
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(linearLayout.getContext());
  final View details = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_details, linearLayout, false);
  linearLayout.addView(details);

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.extra_details) != null){
                        linearLayout.removeView(details);
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
```

the same use scenario is in the context of onClickListener.
Check more here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 1):

//add view

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
final View buttons = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity, null );
addContentView(buttons, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

//remove view

```
((ViewManager)buttons.getParent()).removeView(buttons);
```